# Read bytes from pdf, write chars txt, then back to pdf as bytes

Tags: java, encoding, stream, java-io

I want to read a pdf file, write it to txt, then read this txt and recreate the pdf.

> **PDF** -- read bytes --> ME -- write chars --> TXT -- read chars --> ME -- write bytes --> **PDF**

My goal is to have the initial PDF recreated. But in this process the final PDF gets corrupted. I can't open it.

This is for learning purposes, so no need for tool recomandations. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Thank you, my code below.

```
public class ByteToChar {

    private static final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 8;
    private static final String BYTE_INPUT_FILE = "mypdf.pdf";
    private static final String CHAR_OUTPUT_FILE = "bytesOut.txt";
    private static final String BYTE_OUTPUT_FILE = "bytesPdf.pdf";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Reads pdf's bytes, and writes txt's chars
        byteToChar();

        // Reads previous txt's chars and writes pdf's bytes
        charToByte();
    }

    public static void byteToChar() throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(BYTE_INPUT_FILE));
             FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(CHAR_OUTPUT_FILE)) {
            while (in.read(buffer) != -1) {
                String decoded = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                fileWriter.write(decoded.toCharArray());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void charToByte() throws IOException {
        char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(CHAR_OUTPUT_FILE), "UTF-8"));
             OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(BYTE_OUTPUT_FILE)) {
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(line.getBytes());
            }
        }
    }

}
```